# Android Google Drive Api - .google_apis folder on git

Tags: android, git, google-drive-api

I would like to start using Google-Drive-API in Android application, which source code is stored using GIT. (Project was created with android tools and google eclipse plugin for drive support)

I would like to know, if i need to store

```
.google_apis
```

directory together with source code?

I can see that there are some json descriptors and jar files. I guess that those are some update informations for plugin, but is it safe to add them to my

```
.gitignore
```

[File](http://gitignore.io/api/android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.google_apis` directory contains the dependencies. If you have a better strategy to distribute the jars, property files and etc during development and deployment, you may like to not to keep them on git.

In any case, you can manually re-add the Google API libraries with the eclipse plugin and you'll be all set again. But, I'd still recommend you to store your dependencies on your side though.